# Why does query group names into single row

Tags: mysql

I'm running this query where I want to check the names of items that the seller is selling and also to count them.

`SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS how_many_items FROM items WHERE seller_id=6`

Then when I try to achieve this result only with one command works.

`SELECT name FROM items WHERE seller_id=6`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(`name`) AS `how_many_items `
FROM items WHERE seller_id=6
GROUP BY `name`
```

`COUNT`is causing your results to be grouped into a single line, use `GROUP BY` to distinguish the results by the `name` field

See more examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

you need a GROUP BY clause

SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS how_many_items 
   FROM items 
   WHERE seller_id=6 
   GROUP BY name